Codeigniter - I'm having an issue with the dropdown it’s not populating the dropdown as expected, and I’m not sure what the exact problem is
When I tried to print the data, it is being printed correctly. However, I'm having trouble with the view file it’s not populating the dropdown as expected. If anyone knows what might be wrong, please let me know. I think it could be a silly mistake, but I'm not sure what it is. 
profile.php - view file
<!-- irrelevant HTML markup-->
<select class="form-select" name="country">
    <option value="">Select Country</option>
    <?php if (!empty($countries)): ?>
        <?php foreach ($countries as $country): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $country['country_id']; ?>">
                <?php echo $country['country_name']; ?>
            </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif;?>
</select>
<!-- irrelevant HTML markup-->

Countries_data.php -  Model
<?php
class Countries_data extends CI_Model {
  public function get_countries() {
   $sql = "SELECT country_id, country_name FROM tbl_countries";
   $query = $this->db->query($sql);

    return $query->result_array();
  }
}

?>

Countries.php - Controller
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Countries extends CI_Controller {
  public function __construct()
  {
      parent::__construct();
      $this->load->model('Countries_data');
  }

  public function index() {
      $data['countries'] = $this->Countries_data->get_countries();
      $this->load->view('profile', $data);
  }
}

?>


This question Needs Debugging Details. It is your responsibility to narrow down the failure by running diagnostics to determine which layer is or is not working as expected.

Could you please add the data that is being fetched from database by printing on the webpage temporarily. The exact format of data received may help to debug the problem quicker

@Master_Nachi It’s working now! It wasn’t working earlier because of a silly routing mistake. I wasn’t aware that we have to provide the direct path to our controller with the related function... which i figured it out later.
Anyways thanks for asking! :)

@Manish Please write your correct code , so that other users in future will help.
